# Is Independent Apple Watch app supports no Cellular's Watch to access network when connected to a paired iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, apple-watch

I have a independent Apple Watch app and a Watch Series 6 without Cellular.
When I try to use URLSession to connect the internet, then i got a error, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

```
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
//        configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true
//        configuration.waitsForConnectivity = true
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://www.baidu.com")!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let unwrappedData = data else { return }
        do {
            let str = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: .allowFragments)
            print("str is \(str)")
        } catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Can you verify that your Watch is connected to the internet by checking if other apps (for example the App Store) can retrieve data? On a non-cellular device, the system will first decide whether it's more efficient to connect through your paired iPhone or to connect through a WiFi network (if your Watch is connected to one).

Comment: Yes, we confirmed that the watch is connected to WiFi, because when we turn off the paired phone, the network can be accessed normally.

Comment: I had a similar issue but with CloudKit on watchOS. I resolved my issue by changing `operation.qualityOfService`. By default this is set to .background, which severely impacts network speeds. I changed it to `.userInteractive` and saw a huge difference. Perhaps you could try the same?

Comment: `let queue = OperationQueue() queue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: queue)`, I try this is still not work.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you in India by any chance? baidu.com has been blocked in India since August 2020, that could be the reason for this error.

Comment: Hey I am also facing the same issue . Any solution